# Wrong thing with the template of SQL call

Tags: php, sql

```
while ($post = $db->fetch_array($lastquery)) {

if ($post['tag']) {

  $prefix = ' <div id="catt">#';
  $tag = explode( ',', $post['tag'] );
  $hashtag.=$prefix . implode( '</div>' . $prefix, $tag ) . '</div>';

  }

  else { $hashtag=""; }

$template .='  <div> '.$hashtag.'  </div>  ';

}
```

**This sends something like this:**

-1 Post number one hashtags: {$numbers1}

-2 Post number two hashtags: {$numbers1}{$numbers2}

-3 Post number three hashtags: {$numbers1}{$numbers2}{$numbers3}

**and thats the same for all. how can I stop this like this:**

-1 Post number one hashtags: {$numbers1}

-2 Post number two hashtags: {$numbers2}

-3 Post number three hashtags: {$numbers3}

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assigning the value to variable, not concatenate

```
$hashtag = $prefix . implode( '</div>' . $prefix, $tag ) . '</div>';
```

look at [php string operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: So all the problem was:   $hashtag.=$prefix . implode( '</div>' . $prefix, $tag ) . '</div>'; ?
Wow I don´t know how this can be possible hahaha thanks a lot!